# I am trying to understand if my data are MAR and if using REML is a sufficient solution to dealing with this

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, reml

I am analyzing longitudinal data from high school students measured across 4 waves (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013). Of course not all high school students were Freshmen in 2010 so I have missing data for those who were Sophomores and up, for example here are those we have data for (x):

|  | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Freshmen | x | x | x | x |
| Sophmore | - | x | x | x |
| Jr | - | - | x | x |
| Sr | - | - | - | x |

Would these data be considered MAR or MNAR? I have missingness and the missingness is directly tied to a variable I have (grade level at Wave 1).

My next question is does running my model using REML fully resolve concerns related to this missingness? I have heard this but I cannot find an article supporting that it is so. Ideally a research article I could cite to alleviate reviewer concerns. For additional context, this is a longitudinal multilevel model.

In all my questions are:

-Are my data MAR or MNAR?

-If they are MAR, does running my MLM using REML resolve this problem?

-If they are MNAR, does running my MLM using REML resolve this problem?

-Also, if they are MAR and running my MLM using REML does resolve this problem do I have to include grade at Wave 1 in my model as a predictor?

Feel free to share if you have additional concerns I am overlooking. Thank you so much!